# Is there a way to wrap items to next line of parent div with CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to position Items "inline" behind Text. And when they wrap, they should be wrapped directly under Text. I don't want to change HTML markup, since my actual use case is more complicated and won't allow that. Is something like that possible?

```css
.outer-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using inline-flex, but it didn't work.

Current :

[image]

Wanted result:

[image]

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hertz-idh1fb?file=/index.html

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin it's not really a tetris-shape here. A normal flow layout can achieve the desired effect using inline elements

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. I stand corrected. Good answer +1. (deleting my first comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need flexbox or any complex layout. An inline flow layout is enough

```css
.outer-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 0; /* to disable the white space */
}

.item-container {
  display: inline; /* HERE */
}

.text {
  display: inline-block; /* HERE */
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: initial;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block; /* HERE */
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: contents`

> `contents`
> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

```css
.item-container {
  display: contents;
}
```

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

Use display contents rather than flex on the item container. Its children are then treated by the flex in the outer container as though they were directly in it.

```css
.outer-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-container {
  display: contents;
   
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 I hope this finds you well..
```

```css
.outer-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  width:600px;
}

.item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:60px;
  height:30px;
}

.item {
  min-width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   
   <div class="item-container">
   <div class="text">Text </div>
     <div class="item">Item 1</div>
     <div class="item">Item 2</div>
     <div class="item">Item 3</div>
     <div class="item">Item 4</div>
     <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Please see expected result image. Overflown Items should be wrapped directly under Text element.

Comment: just check now if it works for you..i have made changes in it

Answer (score -2):

The thing is that the 2 children of `outer-container` are divided by `display: flex;` where `.text` is getting full height :D if you get rid of the `wrap` property :(.

The only solution is to insert `.text` item into the same container where you give `display: flex;` property as this:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 10%;
}

.item {
  min-width: 30%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
```